# NullPointerException report from play store

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, report

Today I got a `NullPointerException` report. I can't reproduce this NullPointerException on my own phones.

I really can't find what is causing the NullPointerException.

Here is the report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.dsf.sdf.ManActivity$25.onTouch(ManActivity.java:445)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3762)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.
    (PhoneWindow.java:1674)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1109)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.
    dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1658)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.
    run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code from line 936:

```
sdff.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            sdff.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().
                getDrawable(R.drawable.pressed));
        } 

        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (play != null) {
                play.reset();
                play.release();
            }
        
            play = MediaPlayer.create(ManActivity.this,
                R.raw.sdff);
            play.start();
            sdff.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().
                getDrawable(R.drawable.button));
        } 

        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            sdff.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().
                getDrawable(R.drawable.button));
        }
    
        return false;
    }
});
```

It's a simple button which plays a sound when pressed.

So what's causing the exception?

Edit:

```
Code at line 445:

play = MediaPlayer.create(ManActivity.this,
    R.raw.bf);
play.start();
auth.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
    R.drawable.button));
```

Comment: Which is the statement on the line 445 in ManActivity.java?

Comment: Hm, `MediaPlayer.create` can return `null` if it fails which sounds odd since your sound is packaged as a resource.

Comment: So how do you fix the Mediaplayer.create being null? Just with a try catch? You're right about the sound being packaged as a resource, but i got another report(The second one). Can it be phone dependable? For example: It works fine on the new samsung devices but crash on htc device because of the nullpointerexception? Is that possible?

Comment: I got the same error from google play and its all reported from Platforms tagged as "other" and it also happens at point where i create mediaPlayer

Answer (score 1):

Rajesh is right,  whats the code @ ManActivity.java:445 (line 445).  If this is the code, its also possible to use the following as your on touchlistener.

```
    sdff.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // dont use sdff, use v param that is passed in.
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.pressed));
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (play != null) {
                    play.reset();
                    play.release();
                }
                play = MediaPlayer.create(ManActivity.this,
                        R.raw.sdff);

                play.start();
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.button));
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.button));
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In any event tho, ahave you tried to debug your application instead? (Right click Project in package explorer > Debug As >  Android Application ).  then this will switch to debug perspective.  Find the breakpoints pane (Window > show view > Breakpoints).  Click the Add JAva execption Breakpoint button (its a "J" with an "!").  Type in "Null" and double click the NullPointerException" that comes up.

Comment: I tried to debug, i did exactly what you writed, but what am i suppose to do/see now? Should i just work with the app until it crashes?